# How to understand $g^{ij}\omega_j=\omega^i$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

What is $\omega_j$ ? I remember the index of covariant tensor is in
the upper right corner ,like this $\omega^j$. And $\omega$  always
represent covariant tensor.So, I'm fuzzy with  $\omega_j$.

In picture below ,is $\omega^i$ coefficient of $\omega$ ?

And what is$X^j$?

How to understand $g^{ij}\omega_j=\omega^i$?

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you have a finite dimensional vector space $V$ and a metric $g$ on $V$, one can define an linear mapping $\flat: V\to V^*$, $X\mapsto X^\flat \in V^*$ given by $X^\flat (Y) = g(X, Y)$. Now let $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ be a basis of $V$, then every $X\in V$ is written as $X = X^i e_i$, or simply $X = X^i$.

Let $\{e^1, \cdots, e^n\}$ be its dual basis in $V^*$, that is 
$$\tag{1} e^i (e_j) = \delta^i_j\ \ \ \ \forall i, j = 1,\cdots, n,$$
Now to found out the representation of $X^\flat$ in terms of the basis $\{e^1, \cdots, e^n\}$, write $X^\flat = X_i e^i$, then by $(1)$,
$$X_j =  X^\flat (e_j) = g(X, e_j) = g(X^i e_i, e_j) = X^i g_{ij}.$$
Thus $X_j = g_{ij} X^i$.

Answer (score 2):

Usually lower indices represent the covariant components (of a covector) and upper indices the contravariant components ( of a vector) You can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Superscripts_and_subscripts_vs._only_subscripts).

Comment: How to understand $g^{ij}\omega_j=\omega^i$?

Comment: It is the standard Einstein notation for raising and lovering indices ( here $g^{ij}$ is the metric tensor): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation